# what is a "sequential recommender system"?

Tags: machine-learning

I have to make a presentation about the paper “Markov decision process in recommender system” from Shaini et al. But they forgot to make a simple definition of what is a sequential recommender system. Basically, the idea is you make recommendation based on the ordered sequence of user’s past behaviour. But how to make them sound academic and scientific?

Answer (score 1):

Please describe what you mean by academic and scientific. Your own words describe sequential recommender clearly and being clear is in the benefit of science and academia.

I think you're looking for a **formal** definition of a sequential recommender system. I would suggest reading about Markov Chains at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain

Comment: thanks for your feedback. maybe it's already a good definition